# Corda - CommonQueryCriteria purpose of externalIds property

Tags: corda

The Corda vault API contains a class called [CommonQueryCriteria](https://api.corda.net/api/corda-os/4.6/html/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.node.services.vault/-query-criteria/-common-query-criteria/index.html) which is implemented like so:

```kotlin
abstract class CommonQueryCriteria : QueryCriteria() {
    abstract val status: Vault.StateStatus
    open val relevancyStatus: Vault.RelevancyStatus = Vault.RelevancyStatus.ALL
    open val constraintTypes: Set<Vault.ConstraintInfo.Type> = emptySet()
    open val constraints: Set<Vault.ConstraintInfo> = emptySet()
    open val participants: List<AbstractParty>? = null
    abstract val contractStateTypes: Set<Class<out ContractState>>?
    open val externalIds: List<UUID> = emptyList()
    open val exactParticipants: List<AbstractParty>? = null
    override fun visit(parser: IQueryCriteriaParser): Collection<Predicate> {
    return parser.parseCriteria(this)
    }
}
```

What is the purpose of the `externalIds` property?

**Note:** This surely can't be meant to map `UniqueIdentifier.externalId` because:

- There is a type mismatch (`UUID` vs. `String?`).
- `LinearStateQueryCriteria` exists to query states by `linearId` or `externalId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was introduced to support querying of accounts back in Corda 4.3:
https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/master/docs.md#querying-the-vault-by-account

The Vault Query documentation mentions this new attribute right at the bottom of the page when discussing owning keys:
https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.8/api-vault-query.html#mapping-owning-keys-to-external-ids

Admittedly it is not very clear and should reference `CommonQueryCriteria` (not `VaultQueryCriteria`) and show an example.

Answer (score 1):

Though, if we look at the [CreateAccount](https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/ff20309f9347ee19a223c86973cb7609f7564434/workflows/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/accounts/workflows/flows/CreateAccount.kt#L44) flow provided by the account library, the `AccountInfo` is created with a `UniqueIdentifier` with only an `id` :

```
val newAccountInfo = AccountInfo(
         name = name,
         host = ourIdentity,
         identifier = UniqueIdentifier(id = identifier)
)
```

while the constructor of the `UniqueIdentifier` has both `externalId` and `id`:

```
data class UniqueIdentifier
   constructor(val externalId: String? = null, val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID())
```

So, effectively, if it is true that *externalId* was introduced to support queries with account, the vault queries are actually using the `UniqueIdentifier.id` of `AccountInfo` and not its `externalId` (assuming that nobody is creating an `AccountInfo` manually overriding the `CreateAccount()` function, as I suspect).

Comment: "There are only two hard problems in computer science: cache invalidation and **naming things**" - Phil Karlton _Seems like R3 suffers from this too._